# How to calculate the magnetic anisotropy energy using the VASP code?

Tags: vasp, magnetism

I want to calculate the magnetic anisotropy energy of the CrI$_3$ monolayer which has 8 atoms per unit cell. I have understood from [VASPWIKI](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Determining_the_Magnetic_Anisotropy) that there are two steps:

1. A standard SCF collinear calculation is used to generate the WAVECAR and CHGCAR files.
2. A non-collinear calculation by adding these tags: `LSORBIT = .TRUE.` ,`ICHARG = 11`, `LMAXMIX = 4` and `SAXIS`.

I also understand that step 2 must be run three times with: `SAXIS=0 0 1`, `SAXIS=0 1 0` and `SAXIS=1 0 0`. But I didn't understand how to set the `MAGMOM` tag in the second step. Knowing that in the first step I specified `MAGMOM = 2*5.0 6*0.6` because I have 8 atoms (two are magnetic and six are non-magnetic).

Could you please help me in choosing the right setting of the `MAGMOM` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the `MAGMOM` tag in the second step.

This is because the charge density (including the spin density which is the charge difference between spin-up and spin-down) is read in from `CHGCAR` and kept constant throughout the calculation due to `ICHARG = 11`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I am sorry for my late response.

Comment: One more question plz: Can I use the HSE06 method to calculate MAE?

Comment: @ChiKou Yeah, I think you can :)

Comment: if I want to calculate the difference between z-axis and xy plane, am I right if I set SAXIS = 0 0 1 for z-axis and SAXIS = 1 1 0 for xy plane?

Comment: Yep, looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks, brother, that was very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I might've made a mistake here, sorry! The NSCF version of the MAE calculations relies on the magnetic force theorem (10.1103/PhysRevB.41.11919) where both the potential and the charge density are to be kept constant and one only need to check the change in the eigenvalues (if you check your OUTCARs, you'll see that only EBANDS have changed). Since the potential also depends on the orbitals in HSE06, the force theorem might not work as expected...